# What is the rôle of 'en' in this sentence?

Tags: en

This passage is from Boris Vian's story *Les Fourmis* (1949):

> Heureusement, ça s'éclaircissait. Il en débarquait maintenant de grosses fournées des bateaux.

I don't see clearly the rôle of the 'en'. Is it referring back to the previous sentence? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vian is referring to soldiers.

The hint is in an earlier sentence: *Plus tard, on a été complétés.*

New soldiers arrived from boats to reinforce them.

Comment: Thank you. Useful to know that 'en' can refer further back than the immediately preceding sentence.